# selecting empty string is SELECT is slow

Tags: sql, t-sql

Working on speeding up a query and I've noticed for some reason the more empty columns added to a query the slower it gets.

With only the Id column the query returns 100k records in approx. 1 second.

If I add about 20 empty columns it goes to 4 seconds.

Questions
- What is the default data type of the string in SQL?
- Any way to speed this up?

```
SELECT Id,
    '' as col1,
    '' as col2,
    '' as col3
FROM myTable
```

Comment: Problem is in your execution plan, because of index covering and statistics. You can speed it up with new index on Id. Your column from empty string is in your case varchar(1).

Comment: @Deadsheep39 but it's only slow when I add those new empty columns and has no performance problems when only using the Id

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on how many rows are in your myTable. For ex: If you have 905k rows on mytable, Basically SQL is creating 20 Columns with ' ' for 905k rows

I just tried it in my own table that has 805k rows. For every increment of Columns I add, SQL creates '' values for each row.

Hope this helps you understand it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The default data type seems to be a varchar(1) -- you can insert it into a temp table and check the temp table structure to confirm.  One option you can try is declare a variable and use it rather than the empty spaces:

```
declare @space varchar(40) = ''

SELECT 
   id,
   @space as col1,
   @space as col2,
   @space as col3
FROM dbo.[table]
```